# word wrapping is not working in BB with custom GridField Manager

Tags: blackberry, word-wrap, labelfield

I am using Custom GridField Manager to display Details in 2 columns, with specified width.
When Value of right side is too big then value is not wrapping to next line.

Here is my class of Custom GridField Manager.

```
public class CustomGridFieldManager extends Manager {
private int[] columnWidths;
private int columns;
private int allRowHeight = -1;


public CustomGridFieldManager(int columns, long style) {
    super(style);
    this.columns = columns;
}


public CustomGridFieldManager(int[] columnWidths, long style) {
    super(style);
    this.columnWidths = columnWidths;
    this.columns = columnWidths.length;

}

public CustomGridFieldManager(int[] columnWidths, int rowHeight, long style) {
    this(columnWidths, style);
    this.allRowHeight  = rowHeight;
}

protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int time) {

    int focusIndex = getFieldWithFocusIndex();
    while(dy > 0) {
        focusIndex += columns;
        if (focusIndex >= getFieldCount()) {
            return false; // Focus moves out of this manager
        }
        else {
            Field f = getField(focusIndex);
            if (f.isFocusable()) { // Only move the focus onto focusable fields
                f.setFocus();
                dy--;
            }
        }
    }
    while(dy < 0) {
        focusIndex -= columns;
        if (focusIndex < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            Field f = getField(focusIndex);
            if (f.isFocusable()) {
                f.setFocus();
                dy++;
            }
        }
    }

    while(dx > 0) {
        focusIndex ++;
        if (focusIndex >= getFieldCount()) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            Field f = getField(focusIndex);
            if (f.isFocusable()) {
                f.setFocus();
                dx--;
            }
        }
    }
    while(dx < 0) {
        focusIndex --;
        if (focusIndex < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            Field f = getField(focusIndex);
            if (f.isFocusable()) {
                f.setFocus();
                dx++;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
    int y = 0;
    if (columnWidths == null) {
        columnWidths = new int[columns];
        for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            columnWidths[i] = width/columns;
        }
    }
    Field[] fields = new Field[columnWidths.length];
    int currentColumn = 0;
    int rowHeight = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < getFieldCount(); i++) {
        fields[currentColumn] = getField(i);
        layoutChild(fields[currentColumn], columnWidths[currentColumn], height-y);
        if (fields[currentColumn].getHeight() > rowHeight) {
            rowHeight = fields[currentColumn].getHeight();
        }
        currentColumn++;
        if (currentColumn == columnWidths.length || i == getFieldCount()-1) {
            int x = 0;
            if (this.allRowHeight >= 0) {
                rowHeight = this.allRowHeight;
            }
            for(int c = 0; c < currentColumn; c++) {
                long fieldStyle = fields[c].getStyle();
                int fieldXOffset = 0;
                long fieldHalign = fieldStyle & Field.FIELD_HALIGN_MASK;
                if (fieldHalign == Field.FIELD_RIGHT) {
                    fieldXOffset = columnWidths[c] - fields[c].getWidth();
                }
                else if (fieldHalign == Field.FIELD_HCENTER) {
                    fieldXOffset = (columnWidths[c]-fields[c].getWidth())/2;
                }

                int fieldYOffset = 0;
                long fieldValign = fieldStyle & Field.FIELD_VALIGN_MASK;
                if (fieldValign == Field.FIELD_BOTTOM) {
                    fieldYOffset = rowHeight - fields[c].getHeight();
                }
                else if (fieldValign == Field.FIELD_VCENTER) {
                    fieldYOffset = (rowHeight-fields[c].getHeight())/2;
                }

                setPositionChild(fields[c], x+fieldXOffset, y + fieldYOffset);
                x += columnWidths[c];
            }
            currentColumn = 0;
            y += rowHeight;
        }
        if (y >= height) {
            break;
        }
    }
    int totalWidth = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < columnWidths.length; i++) {
        totalWidth += columnWidths[i];
    }
    setExtent(totalWidth, Math.min(y, height));
}
```

}

In another Class, I use this custom GridField Manager Class.

```
int[] width = { (int) (Display.getWidth() / 2.9),
                    (int) (Display.getWidth() / 1.1) };

          final CustomGridFieldManager gfm_transactioninfo = new CustomGridFieldManager(
                    width, 35, Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.FIELD_HCENTER
                            | FOCUSABLE) {
                protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    graphics.setColor(AppData.color_black);
                    super.paint(graphics);
                }

            };
            gfm_transactioninfo.setMargin(10, 0, 0, 10);// set top and left margin
```

I add Labelfiled like this,

```
lbl_CustEmail = new LabelField("Customer Email", LabelField.FOCUSABLE);
            lbl_CustEmail.setFont(label_font);

            value_CustEmail = new LabelField(": " +trandtail[0].getFromEmail());
            value_CustEmail.setFont(label_font);

gfm_transactioninfo.add(lbl_CustEmail);
                        gfm_transactioninfo.add(value_CustEmail);
```

If any 1 has idea then pls Help.

Comment: Can you confirm, that in the example given, it is the value_CustEmail LabelField that is not wrapping.  Can you make it focusable and see if you can see it all by scrolling horizontally?

Comment: By making it Focusable, It became focusable but not scrollable.

Comment: I used LabelField.FOCUSABLE. Now can you tell me How to make it Horizontally Scrollable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dividing width into two parts.. but my suggestion is you should divide width into three parts. like

```
int[] width = { (int) (Display.getWidth() / 3.2),
                    (int) (Display.getWidth() / 32),(int) (Display.getWidth() / 1.6) };
```

And differentiate **" : "** with new Label Field.

Here is my suggested code.. I had already tried and it works fine..

```
int[] width = { (int) (Display.getWidth() / 3.2),
                    (int) (Display.getWidth() / 32),(int) (Display.getWidth() / 1.6) };

            final CustomGridFieldManager gfm_transactioninfo = new CustomGridFieldManager(
                    width,45, Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.FIELD_HCENTER
                            | FOCUSABLE) {
                protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    graphics.setColor(AppData.color_black);
                    super.paint(graphics);
                }

            };
            gfm_transactioninfo.setMargin(10, 10, 0, 10);// set top and left margin

lbl_CustEmail = new LabelField("Customer Email", LabelField.FOCUSABLE);
                lbl_CustEmail.setFont(label_font);

            value_CustEmail = new LabelField(proTransaction_details.getFromEmail() );
            value_CustEmail.setFont(label_font);

gfm_transactioninfo.add(lbl_CustEmail);
                        gfm_transactioninfo.add(new LabelField(" : "));
                        gfm_transactioninfo.add(value_CustEmail);
```

And your CustomGridFieldManager Class is perfect..

Just cheer up.. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Finally its done for me. Thank you once again.